# Using biblatex package

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I am trying to switch from natbib to biblatex for references, but I'm facing some issues and I can't really understand the problem. The .bib file I am using is automatically created by Mendeley, it is in the same folder as my tex file and I am using TexStudio.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=ynt
   ]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{LawsCosmology.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum

\cite{Earman2004}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here is the error message I get:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "Ref Laws Cosmo"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.8)
The top-level auxiliary file: Ref Laws Cosmo.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Ref Laws Cosmo.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Ref Laws Cosmo.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Ref Laws Cosmo.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

Also is there any bibliography style that resembles the APA style for biblatex?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You either need to change `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex` or, better yet, figure out how to run biber instead of bibtex. (biber and bibtex are both external programs.) Incidentally, what makes you think that `style=alphabetic` will format the bib entries according to APA style? (For sure, `sorting=ynt` is not compatible with APA guidelines.) Have you thought about maybe using `style=apa`?

Comment: you are explicitly telling biblatex to use the biber backend: `backend=biber,`. So why are you using bibtex? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754/2388  (do not switch to the bibtex backend, biber is much better).

Comment: @Mico thanks for the comment. Nothing makes me think that "alphabetic" will format the references in APA style. This is just an example apparently and that's why I am asking if there is an option for apa style with biblatex. The problem is that once I replace ''alphabetic'' with ''apa'' I get a bunch of errors and the text doesn't compile properly.

Comment: As Mico and Urlike have pointed out, you (or your editor) was running BibTeX when the document needed Biber. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 tells you how to configure many common editors to run Biber.

Comment: If you want a style that is roughly like APA (as in: it is an author-year citation style), replace `style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt`  with `style=authoryear,`. If you want real APA style, replace it with `style=apa,`. If you get any errors from any these things, first clear out the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...), then recompile and try to fix the errors starting from the first. If you need any help, show us which errors you get and share a document that reproduces the errors.